# PHP JSON Response Includes HTML Layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm struggling with an issue here: I'm trying to create a jQuery/AJAX/PHP live search bar. I am calling `search.php` fine, but whenever I output the response in the console, I get the contents of my `master.php` file (which is just site-wide layout) along with the JSON-encoded results. I can't figure out what is causing this to happen.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("#search-text").keyup(function() {
    var $res = $(".search-results");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search.php",
        data: { query: $(this).val() },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $res.show();
            $res.append(html);
            console.log(html);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("XHR: " + xhr);
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
    });

    return false;

});
});
```

And `search.php`:

```
$key = $_POST["query"];
$db = new Database();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE :key OR lastname LIKE :key OR firstname AND lastname LIKE :key");
$db->bind(":key", '%' . $key . '%');
$rows = $db->resultset();

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Herlon Augusto is right add exit(); at the end of the code

Answer (score 3):

Write an exit() after the echo in search.php.
Like this:

```
$key = $_POST["query"];
$db = new Database();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE :key OR lastname LIKE :key OR firstname AND lastname LIKE :key");
$db->bind(":key", '%' . $key . '%');
$rows = $db->resultset();

echo json_encode($rows);

exit();
```

It should prevent showing the entire page.

Comment: unfortunately, adding `exit()` didn't fix the issue

Comment: Is there something more on the search.php page ?

Comment: In the master.php don't have 2 elements with "search-results" class?

Comment: When you access just the search.php the master content don't shows, right? If it shows, probabily the issue is on this page.

Comment: woooooow. I feel dumb. I included master.php because it includes `require` statements for some classes I built. Just completely overlooked the fact that it would output all the HTML from the master page... thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, sometime things like that just happen. Don't forget to vote up the answer to help other people too.

Answer (score 0):

```
In search.php before sending $rows in json_encode() give one condition that will check $row is empty or not.like :
if(!empty($res))
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','result'=>$rows));
else
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'failed','result'=>[]));
In ajax check 
success: function(html)
{
    if(html.status=='success')
    {
            $res.show();
            $res.append(result.html);
            console.log(result.html);
     }
}
may be it will work..
```

Comment: I do need to add this, but in the test I'm running right now, I know that `$rows` has data

Comment: it happens even if I return "hello, world!"